# Can I manually map a file extension to an IFilter?

Tags: indexing-service

I'm working with Microsoft Indexing Service. I have purchased a third-party IFilter to extract XMP metadata from Adobe products.  I'm having trouble getting it to work, and it occurs to me that the problem is that I don't actually have the Adobe software installed on my server, so the IFilters are not mapped.

Put another way, there's nothing to tell the indexer that ".psd" files should use this DLL rather than the default DLL.

Is it possible to manually map file extensions to the IFilter you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ContentIndex`, value `DllsToRegister`. Also `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0\Search\Setup\ContentIndexCommon\Filters\Extension\.psd` should be the GUID of the IFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will work in your situation, but the `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` commands available at the `CMD` prompt might be what you're looking for. Here's the example from `HELP FTYPE`:

```
ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
```